# Gerar pdf em java

Tags: java, primefaces, pdf

Boa tarde, gostaria de uma ajuda referente ao gerar um relatorio pdf em java. Bom estou utilizando do primefaces para exportar esse relatório. Eu criei a primeira linha com os campos como podem observar na imagem abaixo, só que quando exportar automaticamente gera também essa segunda linha, pegando lá do meu datatable, como faço para deixar apenas a linha que eu criei? pois eu não quero que apareça a que vem do datatable. Grato

esse é o meu bean na qual estou fazendo para gerar o meu pdf.

```
 public void preProcessPDF(Object document) throws DocumentException, BadElementException, IOException {
Document pdf = (Document) document;
pdf.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());



    pdf.open();

       PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Rodovia")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Callbox")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tipo")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Versão Firmware")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Endereço IP")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ramal/Numero")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ativo")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Status")));




    Font catFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Relatório", catFont);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

    p.setSpacingAfter(20);

    pdf.add(p);
    pdf.add(table);


}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <h:commandLink>
<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-fw"/> #{bundle['system.ui.label.export.pdf']}
<p:dataExporter type="pdf" 
encoding="iso-8859-1"
target="callbox_datatable"
preProcessor="#{callboxBean.preProcessPDF}"
/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Na documentação do PrimeFaces :

> In case you need one or more columns to be ignored set exportable option of column to false.
>   <p:column exportable="false"> 
>   [...] 
>   <p:column>

Então nas colunas basta adicionar `exportable="false"`que a coluna não será exportada.

Comment: mas se eu fizer isso, além de ocultar a minha linha, vai ocultar meus dados também, e não é isso que eu quero, quero retirar a linha que na qual ele mesmo cria, e colocar a minha personalizada.

Comment: Tem razão @Ivan Dê uma olhada nesse exempo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574259/dataexporter-pdf-header-position talvez ajude